# Why does "build" not generate an APK but the run icon does?

Tags: android, android-studio

Using Android Studio 1.4, whenever I Build->Make Project (Ctrl + F9) or make module 'app' for my app, no apk is generated. However, when I click the run icon, an apk is generated. Why is this? What needs to be done in order to get Android Studio to build an apk whenever I use build?

For reference, this is a simple "Hello World" application created with a single activity via the new application wizards.

Answer (score 1):

'Make Project' only create files to be built.

Use 'Generate Signed APK' in the same tab.

**EDIT**

If you want to build a debug apk, use 'Build APK' and Android Studio will show you a notification with the button to go to the file. Also, you can find it at '*your_project_dir*/*your_module_name*/build/outputs/apk'

Comment: But I don't want a signed apk. I want an unsigned debug apk.

Comment: @Maxthecat Then use the option 'Build APK' and Android Studio will show you a notification with the button to go to the file.
Also, you can find it at '*your_project_dir*/*your_module_name*/build/outputs/apk'

Comment: Sounds great. Total beginner question: where is 'Build APK'? I don't see it in the "Build" menu anywhere.

Comment: @Maxthecat I have that in 'Build' tab. Try updating Android Studio.

Comment: Will do. What version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: @Maxthecat Mine is 1.5.1